# Bury empty conduit next to electrical conduit for future tech?

Tags: electrical, data-wiring

Is it a good idea to use the same **trench** dug for electrical conduit to also use for future lines (internet, cable, xyz tech, etc) inside a NEW conduit or should that conduit be in a separate trench altogether?

Comment: See also http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/66141/how-to-future-proof-a-long-cable-run/66149#66149 Since code minimum depth is typically greater for electrical than data, and since electrical is more hazardous when cut, I usually run data conduits above electrical if in the same trench, often also somewhat to the side. Do not neglect location tape (since it comes in huge rolls I usually go for 6" above the conduits AND in the top 6" of fill.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is a good idea to use the same trench. The other cables such as internet and cable are insulated well enough inside the conduit to not get interference from the power cables which would be my first concern.  When placing the conduit in though, if you can have them spaced a couple inches apart, that should help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same trench is acceptable. However, I'd avoid crossing them and I like the idea of keeping them a few inches apart.

When we do banks, they are very sensitive to loosing data (as you can imagine) so we specify that data lines, (in a conduit or not,) stay 6" away from electrical service lines and cannot cross.